# Resizing image with screen size

Tags: javascript, css, image, jquery-mobile

I am using thw folowing code:

```
<div data-role="homepage">
    <div data-role="content">   
        <div id="selectCircle">
        <img src="res/images/zive.png" alt="Zive.sk" id="ziveCircle"><br>
        <img src="res/images/auto.png" alt="AutoMoto.sk" id="autoCircle">
        <img src="res/images/mobil.png" alt="MobilMania.sk" id="mobilCircle">
        </div>
        <!-- <a href = "feeds.html" rel="external" data-role="button">index</a> -->
    </div>
</div>
```

and the folowing CSS:

```
#selectCircle{
    position:fixed;
    top: 10%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
#mobilCircle{
    position:absolute;
    right: 50%;
}
#autoCircle{
    position:absolute;
    left: 50%;
}
```

everything looks great when the images can have their full size. But I want them to resize with screen size change. So when I diminish browser windows or load the code on mobile (which will not let the images to display in full size) the images will resize to fit div and keep their position inside div.

**PS:** I have tried to display div border and it look like it has height of first image, but I want it to include also bottom two images.

**EDIT:** Here are links to images: [image1](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/255/zivew.png/), [image2](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/341/mobil.png/), [image3](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/338/autoq.png/) and here is how I want it to looks like [image](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/708/vandrackebuttony.png/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using `position: fixed` and `position: absolute` is going to make it a pain to develop responsively. You should try and get comfortable with `relative` positioning and `float`ing elements.

[Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/crowjonah/rQgEN/) that I think accomplishes what you're after.

Comment: Yes it works when you use blocks but not images, i have edited my question so you can view and download images and also view how the final result should look.

Comment: My answer still stands. All it requires is a little fiddling with percentages. Study [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/crowjonah/rQgEN/2/) and really, take my advice and get a grasp on the basic css properties of position, display, and float. It'll make it much easier to build fluid and responsive layouts.

Comment: this works but I must set max width because I dont want my images to by bigger than 100% of their original height. And also if I just pass your code and open it in firefox then zive image is smaller the other two images. I can easily position iamges inside div but I need a way to set div dimensions depending on content height and then align the whole div in center of screen, which is (as I experienced) impossible with float: left. It is also strange that it looks like it is working in your fiddle but when I pass exactly same code and open in in firefox it doesnt work as it should.

Comment: centering items floated left is not impossible if you wrap them inside block elements with a defined, less than 100% width and `margin: auto`. Keep playing with the CSS! http://jsfiddle.net/crowjonah/rhAMP/2/embedded/result/

Comment: Ahm, you're wrong about not being able to use pixels for designs suited for multiple devices – that's where the `max-width` comes in. The last fiddle I linked to is centered and works on narrow screens. Have fun.

Comment: I have finaly got it to work as I want using your last fiddle and few modifications so thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try using window.innerWidth and window.innerHeight. Combined with onresize. 
The links below show examples of how you can achieve this. When you know the size of the window, then you can change the size of the pictures appropriately

links:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_innerheight.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onresize.asp